# How to add new fields in registration form in joomla 2.5 default (com_users)

Tags: php, joomla

I am working on a site in that site I need to customize the registration fields and add new fields in it . How can I do this? I have seen all the possible files but did not find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at these options:

- http://docs.joomla.org/Can_i_add_registration_fields%3F
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/14303

Answer (score -1):

```
Step1 : component/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml ---- open this file and new field what ever you want.
For Example : <field name="newfield" type="text" 
description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NEWFIELD_DESC" 
filter="string" 
label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NEWFIELD_LABEL" 
message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_FIELD_MESSAGE" 
required="true" 
size="30" 
/>
Step 2: Open your database and add new field manually. You are done now. Test your site and enjoy :-)
```

Comment: You seem to be trying, and failing, to promote your personal blog without disclaiming that it's yours.  That's basically spamming, and is not welcome here.  Normally I'd just flag your post and move on, but I figured that you might *also* want to know that you can hit the big fat orange question mark on the editing toolbar to get formatting help.  You need it.  Badly.